# xubuntu error-logs location

Tags: ubuntu, location, error-log

The `etc/apache2/sites-available` file for my website has a location for my error logs set as the following:

```
${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

The problem is I don't know the value of `APACHE_LOG_DIR`.

Someone suggested looking in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` but that file is completely empty. Where are my error-logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system it's the folder `/var/log/apache2/`, try

```
grep -i APACHE_LOG_DIR /etc/apache2/*
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

to find out where yours is. Or check the file `/etc/apache2/envvars` where the variable is set.